# unable to create or update a belongs_to record in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and struggling to get my belongs_to association right. I have an app where a painting belongs to an artist and an artist can have_many paintings. I can create and edit my paintings, however I can not edit or create artists except through the console. Through much Googling I feel I have got myself turned around. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's my routes.rb file:

```
MuseumApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :paintings

  resources :paintings do
  resources :artists
  resources :museums
end
  root 'paintings#index'

end
```

Here's my paintings Controller

```
   def show
    @painting = Painting.find params[:id]
  end

  def new
    @painting = Painting.new
    #@artist = Artist.new
  end

  def create
    safe_painting_params = params.require(:painting).permit(:title, :image)
    @painting = Painting.new safe_painting_params 
    if @painting.save
      redirect_to @painting
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @painting = Painting.find(params[:id])
    @painting.destroy
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  def edit
    @painting = Painting.find(params[:id])
  end
 def update 
    @painting = Painting.find(params[:id]) 
    if @painting.update_attributes(params[:painting].permit(:title, :image)) #safe_params
      redirect_to @painting
    else
      render :edit
    end
 end
```

Here's the form in my paintings view:

```
<%= form_for(@painting) do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>painting</legend>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :image %>
      <%= f.text_field :image %>
    </div>
 <%= form_for([@painting,@painting.create_artist]) do |f| %>   
    <div>
      <%= f.label :Artist %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Artists Controller:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @artists = Artist.all
    @artists = params[:q] ? Artist.search_for(params[:q]) : Artist.all
  end

def show
    @artist = Artist.find params[:id]
  end

  def new
    @artist = Artist.new
  end

  def create
    @painting = Painting.find(params[:painting_id])
    @artist = @painting.create_artist(artist_params)
    redirect_to painting_path(@painting)
  end

  def destroy
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
    @Artist.destroy
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  def edit
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
  end

 def update 
    @painting = Painting.find(params[:painting_id])
    @artist = @artist.update_attributes(artist_params)
    redirect_to painting_path(@painting)
 end

end

private 
    def artist_params
        params.require(:artist).permit(:name)
    end
```

Index view:

```
<h1> Hello and Welcome to Museum App</h1>

<h3><%= link_to "+ Add To Your Collection", new_painting_artist_path %></h3>

<%= form_tag '/', method: :get do %>
  <%= search_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

<br>

<div id="paintings">
  <ul>
  <% @paintings.each do |painting| %>
    <li><%= link_to painting.title, {action: :show, id:painting.id} %>    by   <%= painting.artist_name %></li>
     <div id = "img">
        <br><%= link_to (image_tag painting.image), painting.image %><br>
     </div>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_painting_path(id: painting.id) %>
     || 
     <%= link_to 'Destroy', {action: :destroy, id: painting.id},method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to read up on nested attributes - you can't just nest nest 1 form within another

Comment: Thanks and will continue to Google and read through Rails Guide. The form didn't look right to me, but when I "de-nested" I got errors that there was no title method for artists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you should use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) and [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) to achieve this.

```
Artist

has_many :paintings, :dependent => :destroy         
accepts_nested_attributes_for :paintings

Painting

belongs_to :artist
```

And also you should try creating **artist** with **paintings** like this

```
form_for(@artist) do |f| %>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Artist</legend>

      <%= f.label :Artist %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= fields_for :paintings, @artist.paintings do |artist_paintings| %>
      <%= artist_paintings.label :title %>
      <%= artist_paintings.text_field :title %>

      <%= artist_paintings.label :image %>
      <%= artsist_paintings.text_field :image %>

  </fieldset>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Note:**

You should be having your `Artist Controller` with at least `new`,`create`,`edit` and `update` methods defined in it to achieve this.

**Edit**

Try the reverse

```
Artist

   has_many :paintings, :dependent => :destroy         


 Painting

    belongs_to :artist
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :paintings


    form_for(@painting) do |f| %>

       <fieldset>
          <legend>Painting</legend>

          <%= f.label :title %>
          <%= f.text_field :title %>

          <%= f.label :image %>
          <%= f.text_field :image %>

          <%= fields_for :artists, @painting.artists do |ff| %>
          <%= ff.label :Artist %>
          <%= ff.text_field :name %>


          </fieldset>
          <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
```

Put this form in paintings views.

Comment: Thank you @Pavan. Are saying the form_for(@artist) ...code you have above should go on the paintings controller or the artists controller? When I replace the form I had with this one I get an undefined method 'artists_path'

Comment: @user10596  As i said you should have artist controller for this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask if the form code should go in the paintings view or the artists view? I will post my artists controller

Comment: @user10596 It should go in artists view.

Comment: Thank you so much for hanging in! I uploaded my paintings index view and also my full routes. Paintings index is my root. I still get the no artists_path so I'm wondering if I should change my routes rb so artists is not under paintings

Comment: @user10596 I just changed again.have a lok.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working.I think you meant Painting model should accept_nested_attributes for **:artist** and the form_for should be **@painting**. This cleared the path errors. Thank you for all your efforts, but I think I need to take a walk and come back to it.

Comment: @user10596 you have to.And Can you please accept my answer.